# Stochastic volatility with jumps

Tags: implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, heston, sde, jump-diffusion

I'm reading the Duffie, Pan, and Singleton (2000) paper now and I've stumbled upon something that seems to me as an inconsistency. Whenever I look up the SVJJ model, I see that its log-transform is formulated in the following way
$$
\begin{align}
 dY_{t} &= \left(r - \frac{1}{2}V_{t} - \lambda\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{e}^{J^{Y}} - 1]\right)dt + \sqrt{V_{t}}dB^{Y}_{t} + J^{Y}dN^{Y}_{t}\\
 dV_{t} &= \kappa(\theta - V_{t})dt + \sigma\rho\sqrt{V_{t}}B^{Y}_{t} + \sigma\sqrt{(1-\rho^{2})V_{t}}B^{V}_{t} + J^{V}dN^{V}_{t}.
\end{align}
$$
However, Duffie, Pan, and Singleton (2000) seems to just drop the $J$, i.e. they formulate the SVJJ as
$$
\begin{align}
 dY_{t} &= \left(r - \frac{1}{2}V_{t} - \lambda\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{e}^{J^{Y}} - 1]\right)dt + \sqrt{V_{t}}dB^{Y}_{t} + dN^{Y}_{t}\\
 dV_{t} &= \kappa(\theta - V_{t})dt + \sigma\rho\sqrt{V_{t}}B^{Y}_{t} + \sigma\sqrt{(1-\rho^{2})V_{t}}B^{V}_{t} + dN^{V}_{t}.
\end{align}
$$
(I refer to equation 4.1 in their paper). Can someone tell me why this is done or how I should understand this. Papers that perform some type of derivation from the price process to the log-transform price process would also be appreciated.

Comment: Equation (4.1) in [this paper](https://www.darrellduffie.com/uploads/pubs/DuffiePanSingleton2000.pdf) ? If yes they don't write $dN$ which presumably is a Poisson process but $dZ$ which is more general than that. See their definitions.

Comment: Yes, that is the paper I'm referring to. What is the difference between using $dN$ and $dZ$. I mean if it is clear that it is a compensated Poisson process.

Comment: To add to my previous comment. Would the above two definitions be equivalent if the DPS(2000) equation I wrote had $dZ$ instead of $dN$? i.e. the first two equations have $dN$ but the second two have $dZ$.

Comment: Strictly speaking I don't know what $N$ is because you just posted that equation without a reference. Duffie et al write on p. 1349 very clearly that $Z$ is a pure jump process whose jumps have a fixed probability distribution $\nu$ on $\mathbb R^n\,.$
As I said before this is more general than a Poisson process.